# Евент click по-прежнему срабатывает после удаления связанного с ним класса

Tags: jquery

Ситуация:
имеется элемент

```
<span class="edit">текст</span>
```

и имеется обработчик

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
$(this).addClass('absolute').removeClass('edit');
$(this).html('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).text()+'"><input class="ok" type="button" value="ok">');
});
```

при первом клике по элементу, что логично, появляется внутри него инпут с его же содержимым и кнопка "ок".
однако, при повторном нажатии на элемент (на инпут или кнопку) происходит, судя по всему, то же самое событие, и заново создаётся инпут с кнопкой, вместо этих, с пустым значением, хоть и класс "edit", от которого срабатывает событие, был удалён.

где ошибка в моих рассуждениях? почему так происходит?

Comment: Спасибо всем за разъяснения :)
вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А можно в самом начале обработчика сделать так:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('edit'))
  return;
```

А происходит это потому, что события привязываются к элементу, а не селектору - потому при изменившемся селекторе события продолжают работать.

Соответственно в событии, которое должно вернуть активность - снова добавлять класс `edit`.

Comment: спасибо, этот вариант мне больше всего понравился!

Answer (score 1):

Можно например отвязать событие `click` после первого клика http://jsfiddle.net/3AkaD/

Comment: необходимо, чтобы после другого события (клика за пределами с последующим убиранием инпута) изначальное событие тоже работало. заново биндить?

Comment: Да, или в случае с классом, ещё раз добавить класс.

Answer (score 1):

Класс лишь служит ссылкой на элемент и после его удаления привязка остаётся. Для того чтобы отключить срабатывание события можно использовать либо `$(this).off('click');` либо внутри обработчика проверять наличие класса (если его нет, то `e.preventDefault()` или `return false;` ), либо вообще `.one()` использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добиться требуемого эффекта вы может использовать .on()

в виде

```
$('.edit').parent().on('click', '.edit', function () {
    var $this=$(this);
    $this.addClass('absolute').removeClass('edit');
    $this.html('<input type="text" value="' + $this.text() + '"><input class="ok" type="button" value="ok">');
});
```

[пример, чтобы исключить и будущие вопросы](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/hVMBL/)